# Allow two RDS databases to connect to each other for replication

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, pglogical

I have two RDS databases within the same VPC and with the same security group.

I'm following this guide [AWS: how to enable bi-directional replication using pglogical](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/postgresql-bi-directional-replication-using-pglogical/) to set up bi-directional replication between the two databases using pglogical.

However, when I try to set up a subscription from one database to the other, I get this error:

```
ERROR:  could not connect to the postgresql server: timeout expired

DETAIL:  dsn was:  host=xxx port=5432 sslmode=require dbname=main user=xxx password=xxx
```

I have a rule in my security group to allow all traffic from instances with that security group, but it doesn't seem to help:

[image: security group rule to allow all traffic from the security group]

I also have a rule to allow all traffic from all the addresses within my VPC:

[image: rule to allow all traffic from all the addresses within my VPC]

When I add a rule to allow inbound traffic from all IP addresses (0.0.0.0/0), it works.

Why does my rule to allow traffic from my security group not work by itself?

Comment: Double check that your SG settings are saved and in effect and both machines are part of it.

Comment: I have, thanks though.

Comment: Well, that should work.  I don't see what the problem would be.  Maybe the outbound rules are messing you up?  I've never seen that, but then again I never tried messing with them.

Comment: Yeah, the outbound rules are the default, i.e. allowing all outbound traffic.

Comment: How are you referencing the 'other' Amazon RDS database -- it is using the Public IP address, the Private IP address or a DNS Name? If it is referencing via DNS Name, confirm that the DNS Name is resolving to a **private IP address** within the VPC. If it is using a **public IP address** then the traffic is going 'out' of the VPC and then back in again, so it loses the association with the security group -- the traffic will be blocked.

Comment: I'm using the RDS instance's DNS endpoint. It should resolve to the private IP address. The AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Hiding) say: "If the DB instance is designated as publicly accessible, its DNS endpoint resolves to the private IP address from within the VPC. It resolves to the public IP address from outside of the VPC."

Comment: Similar issue here. In my case, the DNS endpoint resolves to the public IP! It works if I use the private IP instead of the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

One way to troubleshoot this is to [enable the VPC Flow Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html) in your VPC and find the specific records related to traffic from RDS-A to RDS-B.

This will help you ascertain whether the ports and src/dst IPs are what you expect them to be.

Answer (score -1):

This is for sure a Security Group setup error due to `0.0.0.0/0` working.

A security group is not like a typical subnet.   It does not allow traffic between everything in the same security group.

What you want is a self-referencing security group rule.

You need to allow Inbound/Outbound Port (likely 5432) to the security group you want to talk too.

In the "source" use the ID of the Security Group.

Comment: I have a rule in my security group to allow all traffic from the security group itself, as well as another rule to allow all traffic from the VPC itself.

Answer (score -1):

Create two security groups

```
    source-db-sg --> for Source RDS instance
    destination-db-sg  --> for destination  RDS instance
```

- Add security group rules in each security group created above.

```
source-db-sg:
    -- inbound at 5432 from sg(destdb-sg)
destination-db-sg : 
    -- outbound at 5432 to sg(destdb-sg)
```